# Async operation in an if condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

Once I click on a button, it calls the following check function which calls `isReady()` function which does some operations to find out whether or not it is true.

When I was checking, `isReady()` method actually returns false, but it returns `Success` in the console, it seems it does not wait async call to finish.

```
async check() {

   if(await this.isReady(this.entireSchool))
   {
      console.log ("Success")
   }
   else
   {
      console.log ("Fail")
   }
}

async isReady(classes: Class)
{
  // does not include code here, 
  //during the test it returns false, it has been confirmed.
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I make `isReady` return false, I get `Fail`. Can you make a snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: declare a `var result = await anAsyncFunction();` and then if.  Change `async` to `async function`

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce this either – if `isReady` returns `false`, `check` will print "fail" in the console.

```js
async function isReady() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      window.setTimeout(() => resolve(false), 1000);
    });
}

async function check() {
  if (await isReady()) {
    console.log("success");
  } else {
    console.log("fail");
  }
}

check();
```